# Sort an nested array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a PlaylistShema with an array or musics. 
In this array of musics I have an `ObjectId` (who ref to a Music collection), an `addedAt` and a `title`.

**PlaylistShema**

```
var PlaylistSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
  user: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'},

  musics : [{ 
    musicId : {type : Schema.ObjectId , ref : 'Music'},
    title : {type : String},
    addedAt : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
  }],

  tags : { type : [], get : getTags, set : setTags},
  createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
})
```

i have a statics to load a playlist :

**Load function**

```
  load: function (id, cb) {
    this.findOne({ _id : id })
      .populate('user', 'name email username')
      .populate('musics.musicId')
      .exec(cb)
  }
```

**i want to sort my musics by `addedAt`...**
but i can't do `.populate('musics.musicId', { sort: { 'addedAt': 'desc' } })` because this is not where `addedAt` is...

i'm very confused with populate when it comes to nested array...

thanks !

**MusicShema**

```
var MusicSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true}
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't sort an array directly in Mongoose. You can clone the data and sort it as a JavaScript object by using `toObject` ([documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)) and the `Array` `sort` method:

```
Playlist.load(function(err, playList) {
    var pl = playList.toObject();
    pl.musics.sort(function(m1, m2) { return m1.addedAt - m2.addedAt; });
    // pl contains the playlist now 
});
```

Comment: hum okay ! that's why ! Thanks

Comment: hi, I have a similar model. When I populate my "musics" field I don't be able to get the "name" or "description" of the ref record. How can I do that?

Comment: You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, about "can't sort arrays", is that the reason why this is not working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191086/mongodb-sorting-object-field-by-id