# Mongoose: Sort by latest Comment.creationDate in comments array of a forum post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, express, mongoose

I have the following object

```
    let threadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },

  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  id: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

  answers: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    default: [],
    ref: 'Answer'
  }]
})
```

Like you can see, an array of Answer objects:

```
let answerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  thread: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // to article
    required: true,
    ref: 'Thread'
  },

  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,  // to user
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  },

  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },

  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})
```

And what I want to do is, in a mongoose query to the DB, sort the threads by the ones with the latest (newest) answers in them.

I tried something as stupid as:

```
Thread

  .find()
  .populate('answers')
  .sort('answers.creationDate')
  .then((threads) => {
    console.log(threads)
  })
```

but no luck with that. Can anybody with the proper expertise guide me in the right way and tell me if what I'm trying to do is at all possible?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check this answer I think this will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715590/sort-an-nested-array-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the sort in the populate step if you would like to sort the Answers subdocument array inside the Thread

```
Thread 
  .find()
  .populate({ path: 'answers', options: { sort: { 'creationDate': : -1 } } })
  .then((threads) => {
    console.log(threads)
  })
```

Comment: No luck, doesn't seem to do anything.
Changing -1 to 1 does not change their order in any way.