# Nested array sort by field Mnogoose Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hi I am trying to sort a nested array by one of the field. My schema and the sort code is given below

```
const MainSchema=new Schema({
   name: {type: String},
   locations:[{
       locid: {type: Number},
       locname: {type: String}
    }]
})

var query= {"name" : "USA"}

db.find(query).populate('main').sort({'locations.locid':1}).exe(function(err, records){
   return callback(records);
})
```

Above mentioned code doesn't give any error but it is not sorting either. Can you please let me know how can I sort the nested array by a field. I have checked other solutions in stackoverflow but they are sorting at different location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an nested array in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715590/sort-an-nested-array-in-mongoose)

Comment: Due to my front end restriction I want to sort when doing the find this is why @saurabh link I cant use

Comment: can you try this? : `.populate({path:"main",options:{sort:{'locations.locid':1}}}).exec(..`.

Comment: it didn't work does it matter if you have multiple populate ?